# pq Undeclare identifier

Tags: c++, mstest, prims-algorithm

Code:

```
#ifndef MST_Algorithm
#define MST_Algorithm

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct pqData {

    int keyWeight;
    int keyDestinationVertex;
    int keySourceVertex;
};

class Compare {
public:
    bool operator()(const pqData& lhs, const pqData& rhs)const
    {
        return(lhs.keyWeight > rhs.keyWeight); //min priority
    }
};

//create a priority-queue of pqData
priority_queue <pqData, vector <pqData>, Compare > pq;

class Edge {
public:
    int sourceVertex;
    int destinationVertex;
    int edgeWeight;

    Edge* nextEdge;

    //default constructor: initalize all data to -1 and nextEdge to NULL.
    Edge() {
        sourceVertex = -1;
        destinationVertex = -1;
        edgeWeight = -1;
        nextEdge = NULL;
    }

    //3 paramater constructor : integers source, destination, weight
    //Assign to appropriate class variables
    Edge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
        sourceVertex = source;
        destinationVertex = destination;
        edgeWeight = weight;
        nextEdge = nullptr;
    }

};

class resultSetClass {
public:
    int parent;
    int weight;

    //Default constructor: set all variables to value of -1
    resultSetClass() {
        parent = -1;
        weight = -1;
    }
};

class graph {

    int numberOfVertices;
    vector<Edge*> adjacencyListGraph;
    vector<Edge*> adjacencyListMST;

public:
    /*default constructor:
    Set numberOfVertices to zero
    display messsage “Default - Empty Graph Created”*/
    graph() {
        numberOfVertices = 0;
        cout << "Default - Empty Graph Created" << endl;
    }

    /*1 parameter constructor: integer vertices
    Set numberOfVertices to vertices
    initialize adjacencyListGraph for each vertex as empty list; points to edge
    object*/
    graph(int vertices) {
        numberOfVertices = vertices;
        adjacencyListGraph.resize(numberOfVertices, nullptr);
        adjacencyListMST.resize(numberOfVertices, nullptr);
        cout << "Graph Created with " << numberOfVertices << " vertices" << endl;
    }

    
    void addEdge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
     if (adjacencyListGraph.size() == 0) {
            cout << "Empty Graph - Cannot Add Edge: " << source << ", " << destination << ", " << weight << endl;
            return;
        }
     else if (source < 0 || source >= numberOfVertices || destination < 0 || destination >= numberOfVertices) {
            cout << "Invalid Source or Destination Vertex - Cannot Add Edge: " << source << ", " << destination << ", " << weight << " - Edge request ignored" << endl;
            return;
        }
     else if (weight <= 0) {
            cout << "Invalid Weight - Cannot Add Edge: " << source << ", " << destination << ", " << weight << " - Edge request ignored" << endl;
            return;
        }

        Edge* edge = new Edge(source, destination, weight);
        edge->nextEdge = adjacencyListGraph[source];
        adjacencyListGraph[source] = edge;
        cout << "Edge Added: " << source << ", " << destination << ", " << weight << endl;

        // Add edge for undirected graph
        Edge* reverseEdge = new Edge(destination, source, weight);
        reverseEdge->nextEdge = adjacencyListGraph[destination];
        adjacencyListGraph[destination] = reverseEdge;
        cout << "Edge Added: " << destination << ", " << source << ", " << weight << endl;
    }

    void printGraph() {
        cout << "Full Graph - Adjacency List" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            cout << "Adj[" << i << "] -> ";
            Edge* current = adjacencyListGraph[i];
            while (current != nullptr) {
                cout << "(" << current->destinationVertex << ", " << current->edgeWeight << ") ";
                current = current->nextEdge;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    
    void primMST() {
        
        pqData extractedPQData;
        pqData intoPQData;
        bool* mst = new bool[numberOfVertices];
        memset(mst, false, sizeof(mst));
        resultSetClass* resultSet = new resultSetClass [numberOfVertices];
        int* weights =new int [numberOfVertices];

        // Initialize weights to maximum integer value
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            weights[i] = INT_MAX;
        }

        // Vertex 0 is the starting vertex
        weights[0] = 0;
        extractedPQData.keyWeight = weights[0];
        extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex = 0;
        extractedPQData.keySourceVertex = 0;

        // Add starting vertex to the priority queue
        // Note: Replace this operation with the appropriate operation for your priority queue library
        pq.push(intoPQData);
        
        resultSet[0].parent = -1;

        while (!pq.empty()) {
            extractedPQData = pq.top();
            pq.pop();

            if (mst[extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex]) {
                continue;
            }

            mst[extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex] = true;

            if (extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex != 0 || extractedPQData.keySourceVertex != 0) {
                addEdge(extractedPQData.keySourceVertex, extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex, extractedPQData.keyWeight);
                resultSet[extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex].parent = extractedPQData.keySourceVertex;
                resultSet[extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex].weight = extractedPQData.keyWeight;
            }

            // Update weights for adjacent vertices
            Edge* current = adjacencyListGraph[extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex];
            while (current != nullptr) {
                if (!mst[current->destinationVertex] && weights[current->destinationVertex] > current->edgeWeight) {
                    weights[current->destinationVertex] = current->edgeWeight;
                    intoPQData.keyWeight = current->edgeWeight;
                    intoPQData.keyDestinationVertex = current->destinationVertex;
                    intoPQData.keySourceVertex = extractedPQData.keyDestinationVertex;
                    pq.push(intoPQData);
                }
                current = current->nextEdge;
            }
        }
    } 

    void printMST() {
        int totalMSTWeight = 0;
        vector<resultSetClass> resultSet;
        cout << "Minimum Spanning Tree" << endl;

        if (numberOfVertices == 0) {
            cout << "Empty Graph - No MST" << endl;
            return;
        }
         
        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            cout << "Edge: " << i << " - " << resultSet[i].parent << "  weight: " << resultSet[i].weight << endl;
            totalMSTWeight += resultSet[i].weight;
        }
        
        cout << "Total cost of MST: " << totalMSTWeight << endl;
        cout << "MST Graph - Adjacency List" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            cout << "Adj[" << i << "] -> ";
            Edge* current = adjacencyListMST[i];
            while (current != nullptr) {
                cout << "(" << current->destinationVertex << ", " << current->edgeWeight << ") ";
                current = current->nextEdge;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    ~graph() {
        // Deallocate objects in the adjacency list
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            Edge* current = adjacencyListGraph[i];
            while (current != nullptr) {
                Edge* temp = current;
                current = current->nextEdge;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
    }


};

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "MST_Algorithm.h"
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    string outputfile;
    string inputfile;
    int numEdges = 0;
    int numVertices = 0;
    cout << "Welcome to the MST Test Program" << endl;
    cout << "Enter output file name: ";
    cin >> outputfile;

    fstream ofile(outputfile);
    if (!ofile) 
    {
        cerr << outputfile << " cannot be opened - program terminated " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    cout << "Output file: " << outputfile << endl;
    cout << "Test Default Scenario" << endl;
    //Create an empty graph and test functionality – No MST
    graph Graph;

    //Graph.primMST();
    Graph.printMST();

    cout << "Testing File Data" << endl;
    cout << "Enter file name for graph data: ";
    cin >> inputfile;
    cout << "File name for graph data: " << inputfile;

    fstream ifile(inputfile);
    ifile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    if (!ifile) {
        cerr << inputfile << " cannot be opened or does not exist- program terminated " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ifile.tellg() == 0) {
        cerr << inputfile << " contains no data- program terminated " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (!ifile.eof()) {
        int edge = 0;
        int vertices = 0;
    }

    Graph.printGraph();
    //Graph.primMST();
    Graph.printMST();
    //deallocate graph object
    Graph.~graph();
    //read from file to see if more graphs
    //end graph loop

    cout << "Thank you for running the MST Test Program written by Amalia Jamaludin(me)!" << endl;
    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Testing Default Scenario

Minimum Spanning Tree

Empty Graph - No MST

Testing File Data

File name for graph data: CIS-Land1.dat

Graph with 6 vertices and 9 edges will be created

Number of input edges to process is: 9

Edge Added: 0, 1, 1

Edge Added: 1, 0, 1

Edge Added: 1, 3, 5

Edge Added: 3, 1, 5

Edge Added: 3, 0, 3

Edge Added: 0, 3, 3

Edge Added: 3, 4, 1

Edge Added: 4, 3, 1

Edge Added: 1, 4, 1

Edge Added: 4, 1, 1

Edge Added: 1, 2, 6

Edge Added: 2, 1, 6

Edge Added: 5, 2, 2

Edge Added: 2, 5, 2

Edge Added: 2, 4, 4

Edge Added: 4, 2, 4

Edge Added: 5, 4, 4

Edge Added: 4, 5, 4

Full Graph - Adjacency List

Adj\[0\] -\> (1, 1)  (3, 3)

Adj\[1\] -\> (0, 1)  (3, 5)  (4, 1)  (2, 6)

Adj\[2\] -\> (1, 6)  (5, 2)  (4, 4)

Adj\[3\] -\> (1, 5)  (0, 3)  (4, 1)

Adj\[4\] -\> (3, 1)  (1, 1)  (2, 4)  (5, 4)

Adj\[5\] -\> (2, 2)  (4, 4)

Minimum Spanning Tree

Edge: 1 - 0 weight: 1

Edge: 2 - 4 weight: 4

Edge: 3 - 4 weight: 1

Edge: 4 - 1 weight: 1

Edge: 5 - 2 weight: 2

Total cost of MST: 9

MST Graph - Adjacency List

Adj\[0\] -\> (1, 1)

Adj\[1\] -\> (0, 1)  (4, 1)

Adj\[2\] -\> (4, 4)  (5, 2)

Adj\[3\] -\> (4, 1)

Adj\[4\] -\> (1, 1)  (3, 1)  (2, 4)

Adj\[5\] -\> (2, 2)

Thank you for running the MST Test Program written by John
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand where the problem is. Can you [edit] your question to make this more clear?